# L-Integral of a series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_k\colon \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\ k\in\mathbb{N}$ be given by

$f_k(x)=\frac{k}{\lfloor \sqrt{k^2x}\rfloor }\chi_{[4/k^2,1]}(x)$.

*Note the floor function in the denominator, it is not displayed very clearly in the TeX code!*

I want to compute $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_k\mathrm{d}\lambda$.

Since $\{x\in\mathbb{R};\chi_{[4/k^2,1]}(x)>a\}=\begin{cases}[4/k^2,1]\text{ for }0\le a<1\\
\emptyset\text{ for } a\ge 1\\
\mathbb{R}\text{ for } a<0 \end{cases}$

i know that $f_k$ is measurable for every $k$.

I can't use monotone convergence theorem, since $(f_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not monotonically increasing. But for the integral

$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{k}{\lfloor \sqrt{k^2x}\rfloor }\chi_{[4/k^2,1]}(x)\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)$ I am not entirely sure how to approach it best.

Comment: Is the square root at the denominator $\sqrt{k^2} = k$?

Comment: No, I corrected it. It should be $\sqrt{k^2x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k>2$, you can write explicitly your function as
$$
f_k(x) = \frac{k}{j}
\quad
\text{if}\ \ \frac{j^2}{k^2} \leq x < \frac{(j+1)^2}{k^2},
\quad j\in\{2, \ldots, k-1\}.
$$
Indeed $f_k$ is different from $0$ only in the interval 
$I_k :=[4/k^2,1]$. Since $2 \leq \sqrt{k^2 x} \leq k$ for $x\in I_k$, 
you have that $[0,1) = \bigcup_{j=2}^{k-1} I_{k,j}$, with
$$
I_{k,j} := \left[\frac{j^2}{k^2} , \frac{(j+1)^2}{k^2}\right), \qquad
j \in \{2, \ldots, k-1\}
$$
and 
$$
\lfloor \sqrt{k^2x}\rfloor = j
\quad \forall x \in I_{k, j},
\quad \text{i.e.}\quad
f_k(x) = \frac{k}{j}
\quad \forall x \in I_{k, j}.
$$
Hence
$$
\int f_k =
\sum_{j=2}^{k-1} \int_{I_{k,j}} f_k
= \sum_{j=2}^{k-1} \frac{k}{j} \cdot \frac{(j+1)^2 - j^2}{k^2}
= 2 \frac{k-2}{k} + \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=2}^{k-1} \frac{1}{j} \to 2.
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate how to write the function explicitly like this?

Comment: I have added more details to my answer.